# Which dependencies do I need for Jersey 2.5.1 @JSON and @JSONP Annotations?

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, glassfish-4, jersey-2.0

I'm using Netbeans 7.4 with Glassfish 4.0.
I tried to follow some online tutorials, but I am stuck at to this point:

```
@GET
@JSONP
@Produces({"application/json", "application/javascript"})
public JaxbBean getSimpleJSONP() {
    return new JaxbBean("jsonp");
}
```

Netbeans cannot find the `@JSONP` annotation. Which dependency do I have to add to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possibly [this one](https://code.google.com/p/jsonp-java/downloads/detail?name=jsonp-1.0.1.jar&can=2&q=). Google `<your class> jar`.

Comment: No, this is something different. But thank you for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies are included in the GlassFish libs.

Either add the GlassFish libs to your projects classpath or if you use Maven add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

As stated in the [Jersey Docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#servlet-app-glassfish):

> If you are using any Jersey specific feature, you will need to depend
>   on Jersey directly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- if you are using Jersey client specific features -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**See also:**

- [Do I need to include the Jersey Jars in my EAR on Glassfish4.0 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600050/do-i-need-to-include-the-jersey-jars-in-my-ear-on-glassfish4-0-server?rq=1)